# Python Google endpoints_proto_datastore list data

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I am trying to create some endpoints for my app engine application using endpoints_proto_datastore it works because the urls return something but just not what I expected.

Here is the code I have I know some of the imports are not needed but they are temporary

Model File

```
import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel

class Estate(EndpointsModel):
    hicid = db.IntegerProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    address= db.PostalAddressProperty()
    contact_phone = db.PhoneNumberProperty()
    contact_name = db.StringProperty()
    contact_email = db.EmailProperty()
    location = db.GeoPtProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

API file

```
import endpoints
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import remote

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
from models.estate import *

@endpoints.api(name = 'raceManagerAPI', version = 'v1', description = 'An api for access to important data')
class raceManagerAPI(remote.Service):

    @Estate.query_method(path = 'estates', name = 'estate.list')
    def EstateList(self, query):
        return query
```

app.yaml file

```
application: yellow-fox
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets

- url: /signup
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /login
  script: main.app
  secure: always

- url: /forgot
  script: main.app
  secure: always

# Endpoints Api
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.application

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: endpoints
  version: latest
```

main.py file has this in

```
application = endpoints.api_server([raceManagerAPI], restricted=False)
```

and this is what I get back from the api explorer

```
{
 "kind": "raceManagerAPI#estateItem",
 "etag": "\"hx0GGGqNWMq76QilvaW15fvq6DI/taVVBKufuJZtJ6w1S7kF6sHCh4M\""
}
```

What i was expecting was a list of items can someone tell me where I am going wrong the documentation don't give me much of an idea.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose what's wrong with such a partial view of your code (seeing none at all of your models nor how you build your application object) and zero of your config (app.yaml).  The `import *`s further muddy the waters as we're reduced to **guess** what you're importing from where.  My recommendation: edit your Q down so it presents a **minimal** case -- just one model, inline, and the method to query it -- yet still reproduces the problem; and, show us your `app.yaml` as well as the results from `http://localhost:<port>/datastore?kind=...` showing the entities & local explorer too.

Comment: I will get on that now

Comment: Hows that or do you need more info just ask

Comment: Seeing the model's code shows the problem, and I explained it in an answer below -- HTH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem comes from using the **old style** `db` here:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
```

and in the various properties of `Estate`, such as:

```
name = db.StringProperty()
```

Rather, you must use the **new style** `ndb`, changing those two lines respectively to:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

and:

```
name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Now, in `ndb` you won't find `PostalAddressProperty` &c, so you'll need to fix those.  But, the general idea is: **always ever use `ndb`, *not* `db`**.

Comment: Thanks guess I was looking at old docs when I made my models.